# Oracle Query History

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have this Java application still communicating with Oracle 11g via JDBC code. With that said, wanted to check the queries made of this application on the Oracle history, if that already exists.

**Key items to look at**:

1. **Full query (with parameter values (parsed and not `?`), passed through `java.sql.PreparedStatement`)**
2. Time of query
3. Schema used
4. User initiated the query

**Expected Result:**

- SQL query to run via SQL Developer (with SYSDBA rights or not) with the key all key items returned

---

Tried using the query below but it doesn't return the key items listed above:

```
select * from v$sql order by last_load_time desc
```

Comment: Look in V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE, and V$SQLAREA

Comment: You can query oracle historical views. Take query of v$active_session_history: this takes about 1 houre of data. for longer time data query dba_hist_active_sess_history. sql texts are on dba_hist_sql_text. for bind variables also dba_hist_sqlbind will help.

Comment: Any shortcuts? Or exact query to look at?

Answer (score 0):

As other members have already pointed, `V$SQL`, `V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE` and `V$SQLAREA` should give you lot of information above queries fired by Java application.

Please note, it may not be complete chronological history. Assuming Java application makes lot of query to database, it is possible that, not all the queries are present in V$SQL (ex: queries which failed parsing, queries which were used only once which are no longer in cache etc. can be missed out). Also, if a query is fired twice (with same or different set of bind variables), you will find only latest execution entry in `V$SQL`

If your goal is to find all queries in perfect chronological order (as some sort of black box study of Java application), then I suggest you enable tracing of the particular session (identified by `SID, SERIAL#` in `V$SESSION`). This will give information on multiple fronts including query fire order, bind variables, performance of queries etc. Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/sqltrace.htm) link for more information. There are different type and level of information gathering that can be done. Also, its performance overhead, please consider that factor if you plan to use it on any production system

Comment: Thanks for the info but didn't expect how complicated things would be. But can't accept this answer since it didn't suffice what's written in **Expect Result**

Comment: Not a problem, glad if this info can point you in right direction or help to solve your problem. My intention was to point out that, V$SQL may not contains all the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Query below should return information which you need

```
    select vsql.sql_text, vses.SCHEMANAME, vsql.ELAPSED_TIME, vses.USERNAME
    from v$session vses join v$sql vsql
    on vses.sql_id=vsql.sql_id
    where contdition;
```

Comment: Doesn't suffice item#1, doesn't return the full SQL statement. Cannot use `SQL_FULLTEXT` column since it wouldn't convert the parameters passed via `java.sql.PreparedStatement` to process the `java.sql.ResultSet`.

Comment: Further more, can you indicate the parameters to be placed on `condition` on your SQL query above with the key item listed.